# "Here." or "Present."?

Tags: expressions

I've heard that every native students say "Here" when the teacher calls their names to see if they are there attending the class.

I recall in an English class in my country "Present" was used instead of "Here". That was started by a student and there's no instruction from the teacher. So I'm wondering.. How does it sound like to native speakers? Is it also commonly used in English speaking countries?

Comment: It can depend on how formal the class is. I remember students using any collection of words including "here", "present", "yeah", "not here" (when they were being silly or anti-establishment)... etc.

Comment: **Here** is used as a  noun, adjective, or adverb. **Present** is used as a noun, adjective, or verb. If you are going to say only, "Present." without putting it in a sentence, like, "I am present.", and it is accepted by the teacher, then using "Here." without putting it in a sentence, like, "I am here." should be accepted too. **Present** :  being in attendance :  being in one place and not elsewhere--Webster's. **Here**.: in this place : at this location--Webster's. **I am in attendance. I am at this location.** Both tell the teacher WHERE you are at. After all, why is she asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard both used. Neither would be surprising. I think "here" is used more often because it is shorter. "Yeah", "yup", and "yo" are also common in more informal settings.

Answer (score 1):

"Present" is the more formal option.